# AsyncTask with ViewHolder pattern doesn't work

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, adapter

I'm trying to optimize my code into my adapter with AsyncTask to do a internet request to read a JSON and display its data.
My code before the change with AsyncTask works perfectly so i'm doing something wrong now because it isn't setting the text after the request is expired. I want that while i scroll the listview, AsyncTask run the code of the internet connection and after it's done, it will change the text into textviews from default to right one.

**Adapter class**

```
public class ListBookmarksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookmarksHandler>{
    private final Context context;
    private List<BookmarksHandler> list;
    DatabaseHandler dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Gson gson;

    public ListBookmarksAdapter(Context context, List<BookmarksHandler> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listbookmarks, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvChapter;
        ImageView immagine;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
        gson = new Gson();
        dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();

        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listbookmarks, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvChapter = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvChapter);
            viewHolder.immagine = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        new AsyncList(position).execute("http://www.myurl.com/" +list.get(position).getId_manga() + "/");

        return rowView;
    }


    private class AsyncList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int position;
        public AsyncList(int position){
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String urlManga = null;
            try {
                urlManga = MainActivity.connessione(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert urlManga != null;
            return urlManga.trim();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            MangaSpec manga = gson.fromJson(result, MangaSpec.class);

            viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(manga.getTitle());
            viewHolder.tvTitle.setSelected(true);

            if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(manga.getStatus()))==2)
                viewHolder.immagine.setImageResource(R.drawable.book_close);

            List generic = manga.getChapters();

            for(int i=0; i<generic.size(); i++){
                List chapters = (List) generic.get(i);
                if(((String) chapters.get(3)).equals(list.get(position).getId_chapter())){
                    double numero = (Double) chapters.get(0);
                    String titoloC = (String) chapters.get(2);
                    if((numero-(int)numero)!=0)
                        viewHolder.tvChapter.setText(numero+" - "+titoloC);
                    else
                        viewHolder.tvChapter.setText((int)numero+" - "+titoloC);

                    viewHolder.tvChapter.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is MainActivity.connessione method:

```
public static String connessione(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

And here is a screen of what i mean:

[image: screen]

"Shingeki no Kyoijin" and "63 - Catene" are the items on the first row (follow the arrows). The others two items in the list have different values. As you see, the text is set as default one (Text) for the first two items and it's set wrong for the last one.

Comment: Yes but what _specifically_ went wrong

Comment: When the request is expired and the adapter is created the text that has to being set in AsyncTask postExecute isn't set!

Comment: Also for 323go to have seen your comment you must tag him with `@323go` in the comment just like how I tagged you here

Comment: There are several problems here: DO NOT call `new Gson` and `new DatabaseHandler` in getview. This is called EVERYTIME you create a new listview item(scrolling up and down).

Comment: Also a red flag: DO NOT have an `AsyncTask` in your `*Adapter` and the way you are calling it is wrong. It will not bind correctly to that correct view.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Thanks, optimized now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ViewHolder is specific to an item not the whole adapter, so move the ViewHolder variable declaration inside the `getItem` method. Now you see the problem: the AsyncTask does not see any ViewHolders.

Instead of `int position` (which you don't use) let the async task constructor take a `ViewHolder` parameter. Furthermore declare your custom async task as  `static` like so:

```
private static class AsyncList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

By doing this you ensure that you cannot access anything you don't need to / should not have access to from inside the async task.

Suggestion: Move the JSON parsing to background (and change the async task result type to `MangaSpec`).

Comment: When using the ViewHolder in the AsyncTask, the ViewHolder will need to have a reference to that AsyncTask so when the view is recycled, the download in progress can be canceled.  Even if you do that though, using the VIewHolder means that the same data will be downloaded over and over again as the user scrolls.  Of course, you could have a flag to not start the download, but then you would need to store that flag somewhere in the adapter list...  It's just more straightforward to download the data to the adapter and have the ListView update from that.

Comment: I use the "position" variable at the: if(((String) chapters.get(3)).equals(list.get(position).getId_chapter())) line so i can't remove it. I moved also the json parsing to background as you said now also if it loads chapters correctly but for the first item it loops through all chapters till he found the one correct to set. Not easy to explain..

Comment: I finally fixed it all, now i think it's way better than before, thanks!

Comment: @Fondesa Glad I could help. Please read krislarson's comment if you didn't. You'll need to implement this to avoid unwanted behavior when you're e.g. scrolling quickly throuigh the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that you have declared a single ViewHolder to handle all the views in your adapter.

So here's how the problem happens:

1. ListView calls `getView()` in your adapter for the first item.  Since there are no views to recycle, you inflate a view, create a ViewHolder, and start a download.  ListView draws the first item using the values from your inflated layout.
2. ListView calls `getView()` two more times to draw the other items while the download is still in progress.  Since there's only one `viewHolder` for the entire adapter, each time you say `viewHolder = new ViewHolder()` you are *replacing the ViewHolder created by the previous item*.
3. The download for the first item completes.  But since you overwrote the ViewHolder, the data for the download of the **first** position is being written into the views for the ViewHolder of the **third** position.  Once the other downloads complete, they are also being written into this same ViewHolder.

I would imagine that if you scroll this list up and down, you will see items changing pretty randomly as you scroll your list.

Now, even if you do fix your code to have an individual ViewHolder for each view, you will still have problems because view recycling will cause your downloaded data to draw in the wrong place when a view is recycled between the download start and the download end.

In addition, you have set up a situation where the same server data will be downloaded over and over as the user scrolls up and down, and that is not efficient.

Here is what I think you should do:

If your list item has a title, a chapter, and an image, then you should create a model class that has a String property for the title, a String property for the chapter, and a String property for the image name or image URL.  Let's call this class `Bookmark`.

Because Android UI uses the Model/View/Controller pattern, what that means is that whatever is in the adapter list should be the actual data that is displayed.  It looks like you are passing the array of bookmark ids that are not what is displayed in the list item.

Create an `ArrayList<Bookmark>`.  Then for each BookmarksHandler in your list, create a blank Bookmark object, add it to the list then hand this list to the ArrayAdapter.  This means you have a list of blank items to start.

Your `getView()` method will simply pull whatever data is in Bookmark list position *n* to create the view for item position *n*.  If you use a ViewHolder in `getView()`, make sure you create a new ViewHolder that is not shared with other items.

Start your data download.  It looks like your REST interface can only get one bookmark at a time.  If there is a way you could change it so you could post all the bookmark ids in the list and get one big JSON array back with all your bookmark data, that would be more efficient.

When your data download completes, you would loop through your JSON data and update each blank Bookmark item in the adapter's ArrayList, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.  This tells the ListView that its backing data has changed and it's time to update the ListView on the screen.

The biggest thing to know here is that the downloaded data should go into the adapter data so your `getView()` can create a list item from it.  Going directly to the view from a download is only for the actual image.

The image download is not a trivial task.  For that I refer you to [this excellent article on the Android Developer's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) which explains it way better than I can.

I hope this has been helpful; I know it's a lot to digest.  For further information, look for more tutorials online on how to update ListViews with downloaded data.

Comment: i have arraylist of items with initially stores likes count if user opened the app and click on the store for ;like after getting the webservice data with after updated likes count set to that textview how to solve this please help me